# Java interface inheritance and implementation

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I saw in the apache camel source code that

```
public class DefaultCamelContext extends ServiceSupport implements CamelContext, Service
```

My question is why this definition since

`public interface CamelContext extends Service`

and also

`public abstract class ServiceSupport implements Service`

Shouldn't it be just

```
public class DefaultCamelContext extends ServiceSupport implements CamelContext
```

?

Is the explicit 'implements Service' needed and I am missing something?
Generally is there any case where this might be needed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362770/should-be-an-java-interface-that-is-inherited-from-base-class-implemented-expli

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not needed, but it emphasizes to anyone reading the code that it really does implement Service - it means they don't need to look at ServiceSupport to find that out.

I don't tend to do it myself, but there's nothing *wrong* with doing it.